# Removing blank fields from a delimited file using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv

Using VB.NET (VS2013) I'd like to read a delimited file and remove a field if all records have the same blank field (could be multiple fields per record).  The delimited file can have "x" number of columns and "y" number of rows and once the blank fields are removed, I need to write it back out as a new delimited file.

The input file will have a header that has to be maintained and the order of the records has to be maintained.  I'm familiar with using TextParser to read the file and familiar with writing the file -- what I need help with is reading for a blank field and removing it if it exists across the entire file.

I was thinking I would have to use a datagrid but never used them so looking for some insight to point me in the direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a certain field or any field?  When you write it back out, does the column/field stay or go?  What kind of demimited file?  CSV, TabDelimited?

Comment: It could be any field (the only known field that will have information is the header record).  When writing it back out, the header should be removed if the column has no other data.

Comment: Many, many unknowns, but the *reason* parse tools like TextFieldParse exist is because it is very dangerous to use String.Split to parse files, so trad lightly in that direction.  You may be able to use OleDB to import the file; then perhaps use filters to determine which rows to get rid of; getting rid of the unwanted columns would be easy too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each line is delimited with a newline... open as a text file, read a line at a time and use the Split method to break up the line into an array of strings. The split method will take an argument that defines the delimiter you are using. Open the destination file and write the array of strings using a loop.

Comment: I know how to read a file and parse or split it into an array.  The question is determining if a field is empty in all records; don't write it out.

Comment: You can read the entire set of records into an ArrayList or similar data structure, then write a loop, stepping through all the records to look for blank fields. It's rote but it works.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

After thinking about it, you may have records that have a couple of blank columns and the rest have data.  I'm not sure if you'd want to remove those columns, because you would lose the structure of the row if you did.

So instead of using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, you can just do the `Split()` and then perform some `Linq` to find out if the `Split()` produced an array of empty strings.

Something like (with the same results)...

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim data As String = "|||||"
        Dim pieces As String() = data.Split("|"c)
        If pieces.Where(Function(p) String.IsNullOrEmpty(p) = False).Count = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("All elements are empty")
        Else
            ' Do something
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DITKW4)

### OLD ANSWER

The `String.Split()` has an overload that excepts `StringSplitOptions`.  Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` with your `String.Split()` and if all records are blank then you'll end up with an array with a length of 0 that you can ignore.

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim data As String = "|||||"
        Dim pieces As String() = data.Split(new Char() {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If pieces.length = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("All elements are empty")
        Else
            ' Do something
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
All elements are empty
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HjmOHF)